# Fork when using socket programming

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, fork

I'm having trouble understanding fork when using sockets. I understand that fork is so you can handle multiple clients at the same time, but then I'm not sure if it should be used in the following scenario:

I'm creating a mock of a P2P server. I must have a tracker and a peer. The tracker handles connections from all peers. When a peer first connects to the tracker, it sends a list of its files to the tracker and then the tracker saves all the files in a collection (including ip addresses) (the collection has the files from all the peers). Also, if a peer exits, then the tracker removes that peer's files from the collection (the ones that contain its ip address). The tracker will send any peer the entire listing of files if it receives a "get files" command.

Here I dont understand how I can use fork (or if it's even necessary), because if I were to use fork, then when a client exits, I will remove its files from the list but since its in its own process, how will the list be changed outside of the child process?

Comment: It sounds like you're attempting a task that's way too advanced for your skill set. But if you must do it, I'd strongly suggest starting with a `poll` loop architecture using a single process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a single process (using either threads or a loop around a discovery function like `select` or `poll`) or use some way to synchronize information across processes such as a file, a database, or shared memory.

Comment: would it be possible to use shared memory when I do not know the size of the list of files (It could be millions of files)? I was thinking of using a linked list structure but could I share this by simply just sharing memory containing the head and tail of the list?

Comment: @Rachelle Shared memory is the most complicated solution. I wouldn't attempt it until you're familiar with simpler solutions. For now, I'd suggest either using a database library or sticking to a single process using a `poll` loop.

Comment: There is nothing specially complicated in shared memory as compared to the complexity of the whole solution. But I agree with David in main thing - start slowly. Build a single-threaded version with poll first.